# Is the Floo Network completely traceable in Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter

The Floo Network is generally tracked by the Ministry of Magic but I was wondering are there other ways of tracking someone if they use a Floo Network that's not being traced by the Ministry?

Comment: What do you mean "Hamilonian path" ?

Comment: What do you mean by "completely traceable"? In numerous episodes in the books (5 and 7) it is stated that the Floo Network IS CONTROLLED BY the Ministry and any activity in it will be detected, or even intercepted.

Comment: @TimSparrow I _think_ this is asking whether one could establish a "parallel" Floo Network, unknown to the Ministry. BookishObsession, care to calrify? :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the Ministry can track *all* Floo travelers. However, in *The Order of the Phoenix*, Umbridge manages to catch Sirius in the Gryffindor common room fireplace and is able to track them from there.